# Jenkins ver. 2.121.3 + MacOS + logged in admin user not see "Jenkins Manage"

Tags: macos, jenkins, admin

Environment: a)MacOS:10.11.6, b)Jenkins ver. 2.121.3, c)user: admin.

Problem statement: An user1 who has "admin" privilege, unable to see the "manage jenkins" after log in.

Description: when a admin user, logged in, he not able to see the "Manage Jenkins" option.

Comment: After adopting the "Role based strategy"

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it in this way:

Step-1) Goto: ${JENKINS_HOME} directory.

Step-2) Open: "config.xml".

Step-3) Goto: authorizationStrategy tag.

Step-4) Goto: roleMap tag, with type="globalRoles".

Step-5) Goto: role tag, with name="admin" pattern=".*" .

Step-6) Goto: assignedSIDs tag.

Step-7) Goto: sid tag.

Step-8) replace the id with all lowercase.

i) Before changing to lowercase, value of sid tag is: "AdminUser".

ii) After changing to lowercase, value of sid tag is: "adminuser".

Step-9) Restart the Jenkins.

$ java -jar jenkins.war.

Step-10) Goto browser, and logged in as "adminuser". You will now see the "Manage Jenkins" options.

Thats all. Hope it may help someone.